# How to change a plot when hovering over elements in Shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, ggplot2, shiny

I am searching for a solution to change a plot in a Shiny app when the user is hovering over a hyperlink in the same panel. Here is a simple example:

```
library(shiny)

words <- sort(sapply(1:50, USE.NAMES = F, FUN = function (x) paste(sample(letters, 15), collapse = "")), decreasing = T)

dat <- data.frame(words, f = sort(rgamma(50, shape = 5, scale = 1)))

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Playground"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("links"),
    plotOutput("out.plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  urls <- lapply(dat$words, FUN = function (x) {
    a(paste0(" ", x, " "),
      href = paste0("https://", x, ".de"),
      target = "_blank")
  })
  output$links <- renderUI({
    tagList(urls)
  })
  output$out.plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dat, aes(x = words, y = f)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this example, whenever I am hovering over a hyperlink (the hyperlinks in the example or non-sense, but that is not the problem) above the plot, I want to highlight one bar of the ggplot (e.g., change its color). All the bars are 'associated' with one hyperlink as you can see in the example.

The solution should be very responsive (i.e. fast). Maybe, a plotly plot can help? I don't know plotly well enough to say.

I do not have any experience in JavaScript. I would love to understand the solutions, if any JavaScript is involved, so please try to comment extensively. Thanks a lot!

I am attaching a screenshot of the app so you do not have to run the example code if you don't want to.

[image: Screen shot of the example app]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`shinyjs`](https://deanattali.com/2015/04/23/shinyjs-r-package/) package can really simplify these kind of things. We can use the `onevent` function with "mouseenter" as argument to catch those events. In order for that to work we have to give the elements an id, or wrap them in a div with an id that we can refer to. Then we can use them to update a `reactiveVal` that holds the currently hovered element, which in turn is used in a `reactive` that modifies our `data.frame` to be plotted. We can reset the `reactiveVal` by also listening to "mouseleave" events.

I hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
words <- sort(sapply(1:50, USE.NAMES = F, FUN = function (x) paste(sample(letters, 15), collapse = "")), decreasing = T)

dat <- data.frame(words, f = sort(rgamma(50, shape = 5, scale = 1)),stringsAsFactors = F)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Playground"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("links"),
    plotOutput("out.plot"),
    useShinyjs()
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  urls <- lapply(dat$words, FUN = function (x) {
    div(id=x, a(paste0(" ", x, " "),
      href = paste0("https://", x, ".de"),
      target = "_blank"))
  })
  output$links <- renderUI({
    tagList(urls)
  })

  # Add a reactieVal that we can update once an object is hovered.
  hovered_element <- reactiveVal('')

  # Add onevent for each element in dat$words, to update reactiveVal.
  lapply(dat$words,function(x){
    onevent(event='mouseleave',id=x,hovered_element(''))
    onevent(event='mouseenter',id=x,hovered_element(x))
  })

  # Add a reactive for the dataset, which we debounce so it does not invalidate too often.
  my_data <- reactive({    
    dat$color <- ifelse(dat$words==hovered_element(),'hovered','')
    dat
  })
  my_data <- my_data %>% debounce(50) # tune for responsiveness

  # Plot
  output$out.plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(my_data(), aes(x = words, y = f,fill=color)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + theme(legend.position="none")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Wow, nice! I will try that in the actual Shiny app and will report back. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @swolf, I just added a detail to the explanation of the answer; I wrapped each `a()` element in a div with its own id. Maybe you already saw it in the code, but just thought I'd mention it because it is an easy detail to overlook.

Comment: Hi @Florian, I have one more question: My `dat` object has to be stored in a reactiveValue itself, because the main dataset is getting subset by parameters set by the users. Now it seems, I'm getting stuck in a loop when applying your solution. I don't know if you can make sense of what I am trying to say, but if you do: Do you have any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: Hi @swolf, I am not 100% sure what you mean. Could you please open a new question regarding that on Stack Overflow with the desired behavior and the current issues that you are facing? I will take a look as soon as I have the time!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to create a small example, the original app is quite large, unfortunately.

Comment: Just to let you know @Florian , the example has to wait for now. I will let you know as soon as I manage to put up the question. Thanks again!