# Is there a way to highlight text out put from word search with includeHTML and not using Data Table?

Tags: html, r, shiny

[image]I created a text search but I need to highlight the text in HTML page when user searches for a sentence clicking on the sentence outputted as shown in screenshot . the right corner one is HTML file while middle column gives sentence output from text .So clicking on the sentence on middle column, one can jump to that line in HTML file but I want that line to be highlighted

```
library(quanteda)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(purrr)


war <- readLines("war.txt")

war_corpus <- corpus(war)

sentences <- tokens(war_corpus,what="sentence")

make_sentences <- function(word) {
                  grep(word,sentences,value= T)}

sentence_line <- function(word) {
                  grep(word,sentences,value= F)


ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
            
  
  # Application title
  dashboardBody(
    img(src='spsimage.jpg', align = "left"),style = "padding-top:20px",
    
    #fluidRow(HTML("<strong>  Search Bar")),
    br(),
    br(),
    #fluidRow(HTML(" <strong>Date: 07-29-2020</strong>") ),
    br(),
    #fluidRow(
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    
    #tags$head(
      #tags$style(
        #"body {height: 90vh;overflow-y: auto;}"
      #),
      
    fluidRow(
             #style = "max-height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;" ,
        column(width = 2,
              h5(HTML("<strong>Enter a word.Click \"SEARCH\" </strong>")),
        wellPanel(
            textInput("inputString","Enter a word here",value=" "),
            submitButton("SEARCH"),
        
        )),
          
        column(width= 3,style = "max-height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;",#creates scroll bar
               h4("Search Results"), #h4 is for heading font size 
               wellPanel(            #places output inside a panel
               tags$style("#mytext { white-space: pre-line; }"),#css text format
               htmlOutput("mytext")# earlier verbatimetextoutput
               )),
        
       column(width = 7,offset = 1.5,style = "max-height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;",
               h6("Uploaded File"),
               wellPanel(
                 tags$style(),
               htmlOutput("showfile"))
        )
    )

        )#Mainpanel
     
  
    )#fluidpage
  )#shinyUi


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mytext <- renderUI({
    
    lapply(1:m, function(i){
    res <- make_sentences(input$inputString)[i]
    res1<- sentence_line(input$inputString)[i]
    
    tagList(
        tags$a(href=paste('#',res1,sep=""),res1),tags$div(res))
    }
    )
  
  }
)
    
    output$showfile <- renderText({
     includeHTML("www/final_tokens.html")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

using Data Table package and using dataTableOutput or renderDataTable has been giving me error as it says HTML file is not 2x2 matrix

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597530/how-to-change-a-plot-when-hovering-over-elements-in-shiny

Comment: @polkas What is the relation between the question and the thread you link? None, I think.

Comment: So why you use jQuery on in your soulution. There is presented nice usage of onevent function from shinhyjs and with e.g. addClass/removeClass could be a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mark.js](https://markjs.io/) is an amazing JavaScript library for keyword highlighting. It is used in the app below.

```
library(shiny)
library(quanteda)

war <- paste0(readLines("russell.txt"), collapse = " ")
war_corpus <- corpus(war)
sentences <- tokens(war_corpus, what = "sentence")

make_sentences <- function(word) {
    grep(word, sentences, value = TRUE)
}
sentence_line <- function(word) {
    grep(word, sentences, value = FALSE)
}

js <- HTML(paste(
    "function mark(keyword) {",
    "",
    "  // Remove previous marked elements and mark the new keyword",
    "  $(\"#russell\").unmark({",
    "    done: function() {",
    "      $(\"#russell\").mark(keyword, {accuracy: 'exactly'});",
    "    }",
    "  });",
    "}",
    "",
    "$(document).on('shiny:connected', function() {",
    "  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('mark', mark);",
    "});",
    sep = "\n"
))

css <- HTML(
    "mark {",
    "  background: yellow;",
    "  color: black;",
    "  font-weight: bold;",
    "  padding: 0;",
    "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    tags$head(
        tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/jquery.mark.min.js"),
        tags$script(js),
        tags$style(css)
    ),
    
    titlePanel("mark.js"),
    
    fluidRow(
        column(
            width = 2,
            h5(tags$strong("Enter a word. Click \"SEARCH\".")),
            wellPanel(
                textInput("inputString", "Enter a word here", value = " "),
                submitButton("SEARCH")
            )
        ),
        
        column(
            width= 3,
            style = "max-height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;",
            h4("Search Results"),  
            wellPanel(            
                tags$style("#mytext { white-space: pre-line; }"),
                htmlOutput("mytext")
            )
        ),
        
        column(
            width = 7, offset = 1.5, 
            style = "max-height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;",
            h6("Uploaded File"),
            wellPanel(
                includeHTML("russell.html")
            )
        )
    )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$mytext <- renderUI({
        session$sendCustomMessage("mark", input$inputString)
        res <- make_sentences(input$inputString)
        res1 <- sentence_line(input$inputString)
        divs <- mapply(
            function(sentence, line){
                tags$div(
                    tags$a(href = paste0('#',line), line), 
                    tags$div(sentence)
                )
            }, 
            res, res1,
            SIMPLIFY = FALSE
        )
        do.call(tagList, divs)
    })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

The file **russell.html**:

```
<div id="russell">
  <p>
My poor friend Andrei Bumblowski, formerly Professor of Philosophy in a now
extinct university of Central Europe, appeared to me to suffer from a
harmless kind of lunacy. I am myself a person of robust common sense; I
hold that the intellect must not be taken as a guide in life, but only as
......
```

Note that I use the div id in the JS code.

---

## EDIT

Here is how to highlight the whole sentences.

```
library(shiny)
library(quanteda)

war <- paste0(readLines("russell.txt"), collapse = " ")
war_corpus <- corpus(war)
sentences <- tokens(war_corpus, what = "sentence")

make_sentences <- function(word) {
    grep(word, sentences, value = TRUE)
}
sentence_line <- function(word) {
    grep(word, sentences, value = FALSE)
}

js <- HTML(paste(
    "function mark(keyword) {",
    "",
    "  // Remove previous marked elements and mark the new keyword",
    "  $(\"#russell\").unmark({",
    "    done: function() {",
    "      $(\"#russell\").mark(keyword, {",
    "        accuracy: 'exactly',",
    "        separateWordSearch: false",
    "      });",
    "    }",
    "  });",
    "}",
    "",
    "$(document).on('shiny:connected', function() {",
    "  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('mark', mark);",
    "});",
    sep = "\n"
))

css <- HTML(
    "mark {",
    "  background: yellow;",
    "  color: black;",
    "  font-weight: bold;",
    "  padding: 0;",
    "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(

    tags$head(
        tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/jquery.mark.min.js"),
        tags$script(js),
        tags$style(css)
    ),

    titlePanel("mark.js"),

    fluidRow(
        column(
            width = 2,
            h5(tags$strong("Enter a word. Click \"SEARCH\".")),
            wellPanel(
                textInput("inputString", "Enter a word here", value = " "),
                submitButton("SEARCH")
            )
        ),

        column(
            width= 3,
            style = "max-height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;",
            h4("Search Results"),
            wellPanel(
                tags$style("#mytext { white-space: pre-line; }"),
                htmlOutput("mytext")
            )
        ),

        column(
            width = 7, offset = 1.5,
            style = "max-height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;",
            h6("Uploaded File"),
            wellPanel(
                includeHTML("russell.html")
            )
        )
    )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$mytext <- renderUI({
        res <- make_sentences(input$inputString)
        res1 <- sentence_line(input$inputString)
        session$sendCustomMessage("mark", as.list(unname(res)))
        divs <- mapply(
            function(sentence, line){
                tags$div(
                    tags$a(href = paste0('#',line), line),
                    tags$div(sentence)
                )
            },
            res, res1,
            SIMPLIFY = FALSE
        )
        do.call(tagList, divs)
    })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

---

## EDIT 2

Here is how to jump to the sentence.

```
library(shiny)
library(quanteda)

war <- paste0(readLines("russell.txt"), collapse = " ")
war_corpus <- corpus(war)
sentences <- tokens(war_corpus, what = "sentence")

make_sentences <- function(word) {
    grep(word, sentences, value = TRUE)
}
sentence_line <- function(word) {
    grep(word, sentences, value = FALSE)
}

js <- HTML(paste(
    "var $results;",
    "var offsetTop = 50;",
    "function jumpTo(index) {",
    "  if($results.length) {",
    "    $results.css('background-color', 'yellow');",
    "    var position,",
    "      $current = $results.eq(index);",
    "    if($current.length) {",
    "      position = $current.offset().top - $('#russell').offset().top + offsetTop;",
    "      $('#sentences').scrollTop(position);",
    "      $current.css('background-color', 'orange');",
    "    }",
    "  }",
    "}",
    "function mark(keyword) {",
    "",
    "  // Remove previous marked elements and mark the new keyword",
    "  $('#russell').unmark({",
    "    done: function() {",
    "      $('#russell').mark(keyword, {",
    "        accuracy: 'exactly',",
    "        separateWordSearch: false,",
    "        done: function() {",
    "          $results = $('#russell').find('mark');",
    "          jumpTo(0);",
    "        }",
    "      });",
    "    }",
    "  });",
    "}",
    "",
    "$(document).on('shiny:connected', function() {",
    "  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('mark', mark);",
    "});",
    sep = "\n"
))

css <- HTML(
    "mark {",
    "  background: yellow;",
    "  color: black;",
    "  font-weight: bold;",
    "  padding: 0;",
    "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(

    tags$head(
        tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/jquery.mark.min.js"),
        tags$script(js),
        tags$style(css)
    ),

    titlePanel("mark.js"),

    fluidRow(
        column(
            width = 2,
            h5(tags$strong("Enter a word. Click \"SEARCH\".")),
            wellPanel(
                textInput("inputString", "Enter a word here", value = " "),
                submitButton("SEARCH")
            )
        ),

        column(
            width= 3,
            style = "max-height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;",
            h4("Search Results"),
            wellPanel(
                tags$style("#mytext { white-space: pre-line; }"),
                htmlOutput("mytext")
            )
        ),

        column(
            width = 7, offset = 1.5,
            id = "sentences",
            style = "max-height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;",
            h6("Uploaded File"),
            wellPanel(
                includeHTML("russell.html")
            )
        )
    )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$mytext <- renderUI({
        res <- make_sentences(input$inputString)
        res1 <- sentence_line(input$inputString)
        session$sendCustomMessage("mark", as.list(unname(res)))
        divs <- mapply(
            function(sentence, line){
                index <- match(line, res1)
                tags$div(
                    tags$a(
                        href = "#",
                        onclick = sprintf("jumpTo(%d);", index-1),
                        line
                    ),
                    tags$div(sentence)
                )
            },
            res, res1,
            SIMPLIFY = FALSE
        )
        do.call(tagList, divs)
    })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a true question... **I need to highlight the text** not word . **So clicking on the sentence on middle column, one can jump to that line in HTML file but I want that line to be highlighted**

Comment: @polkas No need to scream with the bold font ^^. So you want to highlight the sentences ? Ok I think I'm able to achieve that. For the jump I don't know yet.

Comment: @polkas See my edit for the sentences highlighting.

Comment: @polkas See my second edit. I've managed to implement the jump.

Comment: Now looks like I would expected. +1

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thats awesome functionality . Thank you for introducing me to this feature . I felt obliged to learn java script to have this feature . It will be great silver lining to my first Shiny project . thank you

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent - do you think it is preferable to store the js file in shiny app `www` folder as it seems like I cannot get the highlighting for some reason..

Comment: @d123 Yes, it's better to store it in the **www** folder. But that should work like this as long as you have an internet connection.

Comment: @just noticed that you mentioned you have `div id = 'russell'`- I have `div id = 'numbers'(1 to 2000)` , what do I mention in the `js` for this instead of russell? and also never used javascript file . I m trying to save it with notepad, it's warning I will lose the characters when I am trying to save in `www` folder? any solution for this ?